# Setting up Sublime Text 3 for Rails Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I just downloaded Sublime Text 3 on Mac to possibly replace TextMate.

I'm loving the editor but the snippets are being problematic. I added my old Rails tmbundles, but ST3 seems to default to PHP any chance it gets. Even though it recognizes my files as Rails, when I type `if<tab>` in a .html.erb file, it turns to

```
<?php if (condition): ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

I've deleted every PHP folder I could find in Sublime Text's Application Support folder, but it still gets them from somewhere. Any help?

Comment: It doesn't solve your question, but the problem is that the php html snippet's scope is too big. Reference: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2679

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I NEVER EVER want to touch PHP. I've already deleted all the folders I could find. Do you know of any way to completely remove PHP from ST3?

Comment: cd /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages/ &&
rm PHP.sublime-package, but if you want if<tab>, you'll have to create your own snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this package

```
PHP.sublime-package
```

at this location

```
/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages/
```